# Links to comments on Collective articles don't onebox in chat, which is counter to expectations

Tags: feature-request, design, chat, hyperlinks, articles

[In chat, I pasted a link to a Collectives article comment](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/57170493#57170493), and expected the chat message to expand into a oneboxed (quoted, properly linked and attributed) copy of the actual text of the comment.

[image: screen shot of non-working example]

I know that chat development is not a priority (to put it mildly) but I wanted to point out that this is an example of the thoughtfulness and versatility of the original chat implementation which it would be a shame to dilute. Perhaps the code for linking to comments in chat could easily be extended to also handle article comments?

To demonstrate the existing functionality, [here is a chat message which renders the linked comment.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=65226453#65226453) What I actually pasted in chat was simply [the actual comment link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76665637/coding-library-to-convert-step-to-stl-without-large-output-file-sizes/76668948#comment137578629_76668948)
which I obtained by control-clicking on the comment's time stamp.

[image: screen shot of example with expected result]

(The comment is on a deleted post, so you need 10k reputation to see it now. With more time, I could find more or better examples if you need them - I rely on this functionality fairly often - but searching for examples is cumbersome, and you can easily test this yourself, too.)

Comment: Note: Although I've edited the post to be more factually correct in this case (Collective articles instead of Discussion comments), I am guessing links to discussions and replies won't onebox either.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I guess I was still hazy on the differences.